# Test a Gmail Add-on on Gmail Android app?

Tags: gmail-addons

According to Google in their Gmail Add-ons page

> The contextual cards you create for your add-ons work for both web and mobile versions of Gmail. This means that you don't need to create separate web and mobile versions of the add-on—the same code works everywhere!
>
> Note: Gmail add-ons have not yet been added to the iOS version of the Gmail app.

So the question here is really simple, I have a add-on that I'm testing on the browser, but how can I test it in the android Gmail app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever account your using to build the add on, make sure you use that account on the gmail app on your phone.  Open a message and scroll to the bottom and it will appear.