# Gmail add-on in Android Gmail App not displaying

Tags: android, gmail-addons

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47825019/test-a-gmail-add-on-on-gmail-android-app): I am building a gmail add-on and would like to test it on my Android phone's gmail app. Additionally, I have two add-ons installed from the Google Play store -- Asana and Trello. However, none of the add-ons show up on my phone, even when following the advice in the question I linked.

More detail: in a browser on my desktop, all three add-ons show up and function properly. However, in the gmail app on my phone, none of them show up. The answer to the question I linked said 'Open a message and scroll to the bottom and it will appear,' but this advice does not work for me. **How else can I make the add-ons show up in the Gmail app?** I am using the lastest stable release of Oreo, and I am signed in on my phone with the same Google account as on my computer.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue when I tried to test the add on my android mobile phone. There is an issue with the gmail add-ons, once we install the add on, the add on is not appearing for the existing(Old) mails. So to fix that, I sent some mails from my mobile, then the add ons started showing up.